# Cannot apply bootstrap style to asp form

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to aply the bootstrap style to a asp form tag.
using the below code only shows the components without the frm style
I`m ussing bootstrap 3.3.1 and VS2012
This is the secondary page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Maestra.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Pagina2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ejemplo1001.Pagina2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="form" runat="server" id="frm1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

And this the master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Maestra.master.cs" Inherits="Ejemplo1001.Maestra" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="inicio.aspx">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="Pagina1.aspx">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="pagina2.aspx">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Pagina3.aspx">Page 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Mark Otto</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = window.location.pathname;
            var substr = url.split('/');
            var urlaspx = substr[substr.length - 1];
            $('.nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.nav li a').each(function () {
                if (this.href.indexOf(urlaspx) >= 0) {
                    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your current link to the CSS and re-create it by dragging the CSS file from Solution Explorer to the head section of the master page. Then it should resolve correctly.

Comment: the other style are aplied well it is only "frm" that doesn´t work.

Comment: You will need to look at the css hierarchy. Maybe something overrides the 'frm' class settings. Open the dev tools on any browser and check the CSS hierarchy or computed values to see where different properties are set

Comment: I really don't understand the question then; what is "frm"?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add stylesheet link in the second page's header and check thee directory root ~/css...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Maestra.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Pagina2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ejemplo1001.Pagina2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
```